# Ormlite and Groovy possible?

Tags: groovy, ormlite

Does anyone know if it is possible to use ORMLite with Groovy classes?

Given that ORMLite uses Java reflection, which works on the bytecode, I imagine it would be a qualified yes.

Anyone with any experiences using ORMLite this way? If you have, any suggestions or comments?

I understand I can still access the Java classes from Groovy, so that is a fall back. But heck, I'm curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the latest version 5.0 (at writing time) and it works with Groovy (at least 2.4.4), here is a full MySQL similar -little bit shorter- example (file name Tester.groovy):

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab(group='mysql', module='mysql-connector-java', version='5.1.6')

import com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource
import com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao
import com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager
import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField
import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable


class Tester {
    static main(args) {
        def url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/sample?user=root&password="
        def connSource = new JdbcConnectionSource(url)
        Dao<Person, Integer> personDao = DaoManager.createDao(connSource, Person)
        personDao.queryForAll().each { person ->
          println "${person.name}, ${person.age}, ${person.comment}"
        }
        connSource.close()
    }

}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "person")
class Person {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    int id

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "age")
    int age

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "name")
    String name

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "comment")
    String comment
}
```

Command line runner:

```
groovy -cp "ormlite-jdbc-5.0.jar;ormlite-core-5.0.jar" Tester.groovy
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer such an old post! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3):

I just started using ORMLite, but at least version 4.48 works with Groovy:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "people")
class Person {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    int id

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "first_name")
    String firstName

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "last_name")
    String lastName
}

class Tester {
    def static main(String[] args) {
        def url = "jdbc:..." // elided

        def connSource = new JdbcConnectionSource(url)
        Dao<Person, Integer> personDao = DaoManager.createDao(connSource, Person.class)
        def person = personDao.queryForId(1)
        println("${person.lastName}, ${person.firstName}") // prints 'Smith, Joe'
        connSource.close()
    }
}
```